# how to join or split columns VARCHAR type in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql:

I have table : `id, First_name (varchar), Last_name (varchar);`

How to convert to table : `id, Name (varchar);`   ?

And

table : `id, Address (varchar);`

convert to :

table : `id, Street_name(varchar), house_number(varchar), room_number(varchar);`

In other words, how to join or split columns VARCHAR type?

Comment: See [**String Functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html).  Specifically [**CONCAT_WS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) for combining the name.  To split out the address you will have to use a combination of functions.  Attempt something yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- The joining is straitforward. If we assume your first table is "originalTable", then you need two concat the two fields and put everything in a new table, named t1 for example:

```
Select into t1 id, concat(First_name, last_name) as Name
    From originalTable
```

The new table, t1, will be automatically created with two fields (int and varchar).

2- For the splitting, provided that there are three non-empty sub-fields (Street_name, House_number and Room_number), you can use the following SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    substring(Address, 1, locate(' ', Address)-1) as Street_name,

    substring(
        substring(Address FROM locate(' ', Address)+1), 
        1, 
        locate(' ', substring(Address FROM locate(' ', Address)+1))-1
        )   as House_number,

    substring(
        substring(
            Address FROM locate(' ', Address)+1
            )
        FROM locate(
            ' ', 
            substring(Address FROM locate(' ', Address)+1)
            )+1
        ) 
        as Room_number
From t1
```

For the details of the two string functions (substring and locate) used here, see MySQL documentation about string functions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Spitting, first names and last names are random lenght. Space is separator.

Comment: I have add new column kid_name and trying to join all rows with first name and last name into row kid_name, but it do not work. :

UPDATE my_table
SET 
`kid_name`
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',`first_name`,`last_name`)
FROM my_table;

--------------------------------------------------<br>

Select alone works, but i do not know how to connect SELECT to UPDATE. Can you help me?

Comment: You can check the answer to the second part in my updated answer.

Comment: Try this one for the question in your comment: 
update my_table set kid_name = concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name)

Anyway, it was a new question and was better to be posted as a new one!